# Oracle Getting the Latest Record with MAX

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have 2 tables keeping track of projects and their status.

Each project can only have 1 active status at a time but the table also records the status history of these projects keeping track of when the status change has taken place.

## Query

Here's my query for now:

```
SELECT PROJ_NO, COMP_DATE, SPON_PROG, PROP_STATUS, AWD_S, AWD_E, AWD_AMT, DUEDT, MAX(STAT_DATE) AS STAT_DATE, ST_STATUS
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT prsl.PROJ_NO, NVL(TO_CHAR(prsl.DEADLINE, 'YYYY-Mon-DD'), TO_CHAR(prsl.SUBMIT_DATE, 'YYYY-Mon-DD')) AS COMP_DATE,
  prsl.SPON_PROG, prsl.PROP_STATUS, TO_CHAR(prsl.AWD_START, 'YYYY-Mon-DD') AS AWD_S, TO_CHAR(prsl.AWD_END, 'YYYY-Mon-DD') AS AWD_E, prsl.AWD_AMT,
  TO_CHAR(dlvr.DUEDATE, 'YYYY-Mon-DD') AS DUEDT,
  TO_CHAR(MAX(dlvr.ST_STAT_DATE), 'YYYY-Mon-DD') AS STAT_DATE,
  dlvr.ST_STATUS
  FROM adpcra.ra_v_q_ie_prsl03 prsl
  LEFT JOIN adpcra.ra_v_q_ie_pt_deliver dlvr ON prsl.PROJ_NO = dlvr.PROJ_NO
  WHERE prsl.EMPL_NO = '014209'
  AND prsl.FIRST_PD = 1
  AND (prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UM-SSHRC RGP%'
      OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UM-SSHRC TGP%'
      OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'URGP%'
      OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UCRP%'
      OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'UIRP%'
      OR prsl.SPON_PROG LIKE 'Creative Works%'
  )
  GROUP BY prsl.PROJ_NO, NVL(TO_CHAR(prsl.DEADLINE, 'YYYY-Mon-DD'), TO_CHAR(prsl.SUBMIT_DATE, 'YYYY-Mon-DD')),
  prsl.SPON_PROG, prsl.PROP_STATUS, prsl.AWD_START, prsl.AWD_END, prsl.AWD_AMT, dlvr.DUEDATE, dlvr.ST_STATUS
)
GROUP BY PROJ_NO, COMP_DATE, SPON_PROG, PROP_STATUS, AWD_S, AWD_E, AWD_AMT, DUEDT, ST_STATUS
ORDER BY COMP_DATE DESC, STAT_DATE DESC
```

## Result

And here's a reduced result of that query (I removed some columns to make it simpler):

```
proj_no    stat_date      st_status
=======================================
123        2015-Feb-25    Completed
123        2015-Jan-02    Not Completed
456        2013-Aug-07    Completed
456        2012-Aug-08    Not Completed
789        2011-Jun-16    Not Completed
```

The resulting table just gives me extra rows that I do not want to include.

Basically all I wanted is to get these:

```
proj_no    stat_date      st_status
=======================================
123        2015-Feb-25    Completed
456        2013-Aug-07    Completed
789        2011-Jun-16    Not Completed
```

I just want the latest status for each project.

Could anyone help me out please? Thanks!

## EDIT

It used to not be in a sub-query, but I was just trying some stuff out and ended up with a sub-query instead. But the results either way are still the same.

Comment: I don't get your query, but it can probably be resolved by adding `and not exists(select proj_no from ... where proj_no = t.proj_no and start_date > t.start_date)` at join or where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have this

```
proj_no    stat_date      st_status
=======================================
123        2015-Feb-25    Completed
123        2015-Jan-02    Not Completed
456        2013-Aug-07    Completed
456        2012-Aug-08    Not Completed
789        2011-Jun-16    Not Completed
```

Lets call it `YourQuery`. Just use `row_number()` to find the biggest date of each project.

```
SELECT proj_no,  stat_date,  st_status
FROM (
    SELECT 
          Y.*,
          row_number() over (partition by proj_no order by stat_date desc) as rn
    FROM YourQuery Y
    ) T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Comment: Oh hey, this works perfectly. Although I don't understand it. I'm not really big on databases. But thanks!

Comment: Glad that help. The idea is asign an ID to each row, because the rows are ordered by date desc the max value will always be the `rn = 1` for each proj. Is like a group by. I will share the sql server help  because is more complete than the one I found for oracle. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx